# How to return array of objects from array of array with objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such array:

```
  let findAllSegmentProjectMediaFilesXref = [
{
  it: 0,
  bt: 0,
  items: [
    {
      mute: false,
      startPosition: 10,
      endPosition: 20,
      displayLength: 100,
      projectMediaFiles: {
        id: '123124'
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  it: 9,
  bt: 10,
  items: [
    {
      mute: false,
      startPosition: 10,
      endPosition: 20,
      displayLength: 100,
      projectMediaFiles: {
        id: '1231231124'
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  it: 2,
  bt: 2,
  items: [
    {
      mute: false,
      startPosition: 10,
      endPosition: 30,
      displayLength: 100,
      projectMediaFiles: {
        id: '123111124'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But i need to get array of objects like this:

```
    mute: elem.mute,
    startPosition: elem.startPosition,
    endPosition: elem.endPosition,
    displayLength: elem.displayLength,
    projectMediaFile: {
      //@ts-ignore
      id: elem.projectMediaFile.id,
    }
```

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work, can anybody help me?

```
    const arr =  findAllSegmentProjectMediaFilesXref?.map(x => x.segment.id === currentSegment?.id ? x.items.map(elem => {
  
    mute: elem.mute,
    startPosition: elem.startPosition,
    endPosition: elem.endPosition,
    displayLength: elem.displayLength,
    projectMediaFile: {
      //@ts-ignore
      id: elem.projectMediaFile.id,
    }
  
}) : null).filter(el => el !== null);
```

Comment: _"But i need to get..."_ - Which is the content of the `items` property. So why don't you just return that in the `.map()` call?

Comment: @Andreas because it returns array in array, can you show me an example?

Comment: Your example only has always only one element in `items`. If this is not the case in the "real world", then add an actual (stripped down) example.

Comment: `.map(elem => { a: elem.a, b: elem.b })` does not work because JavaScript thinks you are passing a block. You have to surround the object literal with parentheses. That way JavaScript knows you are passing an object literal. eg. `.map(elem => ({ a: elem.a, b: elem.b }))` See: [Arrow function expressions - Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#returning_object_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) / [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
findAllSegmentProjectMediaFilesXref.map(e => e.items).flat()
```

Comment: `.map().flat()` -> `.flatMap()`

Comment: Which is _slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately_ :)

Comment: But if I want to return from items object only with keys 'mute' and 'startPosition', how i can do this?

Comment: @wefwefцуаefwef Could you please clarify what _only with keys_ mean? If you need elements containing these fields you can use `.filter(e => e.mute !== undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
    let newArray = findAll.map(object => object.items[0]});
```